# User-Defined voltage / current in OrCAD Capture CIS

Tags: orcad

I want to excite my circuit with a user-defined voltage source, such as v(t) = t*e^(t)... . Search results suggested using *bsource*, a part within the *analogLib* libary. I don't have *analogLib* nor have I been able to figure out how to download it.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Use LT spice, it's free and much easier to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B source suggestion is for LTspice. In PSpice, B describes a GaASFET.

PSpice uses the E source. From the PSpice Reference Guide:

```
E<name> <(+) <node> <(-) node> VALUE = {<expression>}
```

Example from the PSpice Reference GUide:

```
ESQROOT 5 0 VALUE = {5V*SQRT(V(3,2))}
```

It's a good idea to have the PSpice reference downloaded if you use PSpice and/or LTspice (LTspice generally understands PSpice syntax and there are things that are undocumented in LTspice where you need the PSpice reference).